Apache Guacamole SFTP Settings
A problem arose during further development of the SFTP protocol with Apache Guacamole.
No matter what I do, the SFTP window doesn't open and the screen doesn't come up.
Other protocols work fine.
public class GuacamoleTunnelServlet extends GuacamoleHTTPTunnelServlet {

    @Override
    protected GuacamoleTunnel doConnect(HttpServletRequest request) throws GuacamoleException {

        String hostname = "localhost";
        int port = 4822;

        Map<String, String> dataMap = (Map<String, String>) request.getSession().getAttribute("dataMap");
        GuacamoleConfiguration config = new GuacamoleConfiguration();

        String type = request.getParameter("type");
        String serverIp = Util.getServerIpAddress();
        switch (type) {
            case "rdp": {
                config.setProtocol("rdp");
                config.setParameter("hostname", dataMap.get("ipaddr"));
                config.setParameter("port", dataMap.get("rdpPort"));
                if (dataMap.get("accountId").split("\\\\").length > 1) {
                    config.setParameter("username", dataMap.get("accountId").split("\\\\")[1]);
                } else {
                    config.setParameter("username", dataMap.get("accountId"));
                }
                config.setParameter("password", dataMap.get("password"));
                config.setParameter("domain", dataMap.get("domain"));
                config.setParameter("width", dataMap.get("width"));
                config.setParameter("height", dataMap.get("height"));
                config.setParameter("disable-copy", dataMap.get("rdpRedirectClipboard"));
                config.setParameter("disable-paste", dataMap.get("rdpRedirectClipboard"));
                config.setParameter("security", "any");
                config.setParameter("ignore-cert", "true");
                break;
            }
            case "ssh":
            case "telnet": {
                String password = request.getParameter("password") == null ? "nnn" : request.getParameter("password");
                config.setProtocol("ssh");
                config.setParameter("hostname", serverIp);
                config.setParameter("port", "2222");
                config.setParameter("username", request.getParameter("sshAccountId"));
                config.setParameter("password", password);
                config.setParameter("font-name", "D2Coding");
                config.setParameter("disable-copy", "false");
                config.setParameter("disable-paste", "false");
                break;
            }
            case "sftp": {
                String password = request.getParameter("password") == null ? "nnn" :                             request.getParameter("password");   
                config.setProtocol("ssh");
                config.setParameter("hostname", serverIp);
                config.setParameter("port", "22");
                config.setParameter("username", request.getParameter("sshAccountId"));
                config.setParameter("password", password);
                config.setParameter("font-name", "D2Coding");
                config.setParameter("disable-copy", "false");
                config.setParameter("disable-paste", "false");
                
                config.setParameter("enable-sftp", "true");
                break;
            }
        }

        // Connect to guacd, proxying a connection to the VNC server above
        GuacamoleSocket socket = new ConfiguredGuacamoleSocket(
                new InetGuacamoleSocket(hostname, port),
                config
        );

        // Create tunnel from now-configured socket
        GuacamoleTunnel tunnel = new SimpleGuacamoleTunnel(socket);
        return tunnel;

    }
}

JSP code:
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String serverTime = date.format(new Date(time));
    String endDate = request.getParameter("endDate");
%>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="guacamole.css"/>
    <title>SFTP</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Display -->
<div id="display"></div>
<div id="loading">
    <img src="" alt=""/>
</div>
<!-- Guacamole JavaScript API -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="guacamole-common-js/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="guacamole-common-js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<!-- Init -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tmpClipboardValue = '';
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        document.title = '${remoteConfigTemplate.title}';
        var t = document.createElement("textarea");
        t.className = 'clipboard-service-target';
        document.body.appendChild(t);
        var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        if ((navigator.appName == 'Netscape' && agent.indexOf('trident') != -1) || (agent.indexOf("msie") != -1)) {
            document.getElementById("loading").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "guaca_loading.gif";
            document.execCommand('copy');
            t.select();
            document.execCommand('paste');
            tmpClipboardValue = t.value;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("loading").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "guaca_loading.svg";
            if (navigator.clipboard && navigator.clipboard.readText) {
                navigator.clipboard.readText().then(function (text) {
                    return tmpClipboardValue = text;
                });
            }
        }
        initGuacamole();
    });

    function initGuacamole() {

        // Get display div from document
        var display = document.getElementById('display');

        // Instantiate client, using an HTTP tunnel for communications.
        GuacTunnel = new Guacamole.HTTPTunnel('tunnel');
        guac = new Guacamole.Client(GuacTunnel);

        var display = document.getElementById('display');
        var GUAC_WIDTH = Math.round($(display).width());
        var GUAC_HEIGHT = Math.round($(display).height());
        guac.connect(`....&GUAC_WIDTH=${GUAC_WIDTH}&GUAC_HEIGHT=${GUAC_HEIGHT}&GUAC_DPI=96`);
        window.onresize = function () {
            var GUAC_WIDTH  = Math.round($(display).width());
            var GUAC_HEIGHT = Math.round($(display).height());
            GuacTunnel.sendMessage('size', $(window).width(), $(window).height());
        }
        
        // Add client to display div
        display.appendChild(guac.getDisplay().getElement());

        // Error handler
        guac.onerror = function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        };

        guac.onstatechange = function (state) {
            var STATE_IDLE = 0;
            var STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
            var STATE_WAITING = 2;
            var STATE_CONNECTED = 3;
            var STATE_DISCONNECTING = 4;
            var STATE_DISCONNECTED = 5;

            if (state === STATE_CONNECTED) {
                document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
            }

            if (state === STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "black";
                document.getElementById('display').style.display = "none";
                alert("Session Closed.");
            }
        }

        // Connect
        guac.connect('${remoteConfigTemplate.data}');

        // Disconnect on close
        window.onunload = function () {
            guac.disconnect();
        };

        // Mouse
        var mouse = new Guacamole.Mouse(guac.getDisplay().getElement());

        mouse.onmouseup = mouse.onmousemove = function (mouseState) {
            guac.sendMouseState(mouseState);
        };

        mouse.onmousedown = function (mouseState) {
            guac.sendMouseState(mouseState);
        };

        var sink = new Guacamole.InputSink();
        document.body.appendChild(sink.getElement());

        // Keyboard
        var keyboard = new Guacamole.Keyboard(document);

        keyboard.onkeydown = function (keysym) {
            guac.sendKeyEvent(1, keysym);
        };

        keyboard.onkeyup = function (keysym) {
            guac.sendKeyEvent(0, keysym);
        };

        guac.onclipboard = function (stream, mimetype) {
            reader = new Guacamole.StringReader(stream);

            var data = '';
            reader.ontext = function textReceived(text) {
                data += text;
            };

            reader.onend = function textComplete() {
                var clipboardContent = document.getElementsByClassName('clipboard-service-target')[0];
                clipboardContent.value = data;
                clipboardContent.select();
                document.execCommand('copy');
                tmpClipboardValue = data;
            };
        }

        window.addEventListener('focus', function () {
            var clipboardContent = document.getElementsByClassName('clipboard-service-target')[0];

            try {
                if (navigator.clipboard && navigator.clipboard.readText) {
                    navigator.clipboard.readText().then(function (text) {
                        if (tmpClipboardValue != text) {
                            var writer;
                            var stream = guac.createClipboardStream('string');
                            writer = new Guacamole.StringWriter(stream);
                            writer.sendText(text);
                            writer.sendEnd();
                        }
                        return tmpClipboardValue = text
                    });
                    return;
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('Failed to copy: ', err);
            }

            clipboardContent.select();
            document.execCommand('paste');
            if (clipboardContent.value != tmpClipboardValue) {
                var writer;
                var stream = guac.createClipboardStream('string');
                writer = new Guacamole.StringWriter(stream);
                writer.sendText(clipboardContent.value);
                writer.sendEnd();
                tmpClipboardValue = clipboardContent.value;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>


I re-configured sftp and also uploaded Apache Guacamole version 1.3.0 > 1.5.0.
But it still doesn't work.
